# Injective self-map - check my proof

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:[N]\to [N]$ be an injective self-map where $[N]:= \{1, 2, ..., N\}$ is a finite set of $\mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is bijective.

My proof:

As $f$ is injective and finite we simply count all images of $N$ which are $N$-many. As $f([N]) \subseteq [N] $, we conclude $f([N]) = [N] $ as both sets have the same cardinality. So $f$ is surjective and therefore bijective. $q.e.d.$

Is this correct?

The approach of our professor is different and I don't understand one step he did:

He took the union of all preimages $\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\}$, which are also $N$-many and uses injectivity to argue that all $\{f^{-1}(k)\}$ are pairwise disjoint and therefore $\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\} = [N]$.

Why holds $\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\} = [N]$?

$\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\} \subseteq [N]$ is certainly true but I don't understand the other subset-property $\supseteq$ which finally shows that both sets are euqal?

Can someone explain this step to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write $[n]$ for your $[N]$.

Your proof is good, just add after "as both sets have the same cardinality" the following "and $[n]$ is the only subset of $[n]$ with cardinality $[n]$".

It sounds dumb but for sets of higher cardinalites, it may be false, i.e. $f[X]\subseteq X$ with $\lvert f[X]\rvert=\lvert X\rvert$, but $f[X]\ne X$. For example, take $X=\mathbb N$ and the map $n\mapsto n+1$.

What your professor did is essentially the same. You used that injective implies that the image of any $k\in[n]$ is singleton, then unioning $[n]$-many singleton sets gives a set of cardinality $[n]$. Your professor used that injective implies that the preimage of any $k\in[n]$ is singleton, . . .  and so on.

---

[Here's an alternative proof that I wrote earlier.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3323351/524154)

Comment: I thought that as long as we talk about finite sets same cardinality and the subset propertey (in one direction) are sufficient to conclude equality of two sets. Why do I have to add "and [n] is the only subset of [n] with cardinality [n]"? What could go wrong if I don't add it?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong technically, since that statement is true for finite sets. It's just (imo) misleading since it does not extend to infinite sets.

Comment: Can you explain me why the professor assumes in his approach using the preimages $\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\} = [N]$ and therefore $\bigcup_{k=1}^N \{f^{-1}(k)\} \subseteq [N]$ without any further explanation? To me this is not obvious. I would have shown this equality/subset-property through another contradiction. Or is there a simple/trivial fact that I have missed?

Comment: Read the last part of my answer. Your professor shows what you've shown: subset with same cardinality as superset implies equality.

Comment: @ palmpo, sorry I mistakenly flipped the subset sign in the above comment. I don't understand why the professor did not explain $\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\{f^{-1}(k)\}\supseteq [N]$. It could be that some of the sets $\{f^{-1}(k)\}$ of $\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\{f^{-1}(k)\}$ are empty and therefore it is not obvious that $\vert \bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\{f^{-1}(k)\}\vert = N$. Of course you can show by contradiction that $\vert\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\{f^{-1}(k)\}\vert= N$ but I would have expected that the professor had included this contradiction or any other reason adressing this issue into his proof.

Comment: yeah, if the professor was going that route, they might as well skip everything and say "Suppose some $k\in[n]$ has no preimage, then $f':[m]\to[n]\setminus\{k\}$ is an injection from $[n]$ to an $[n-1]$-sized set, contradiction." By the way, this is essentially the pigeonhole principle being used (or rather, contradicted), which states that for $m>n$, every function $f:[m]\to[n]$ is not injective. Check out the alternative proof I linked; it proves the statement for all $n\in\mathbb N$ at once.

Comment: yes, the approach by induction is also a good way and even more intuitive to me. However, there is one step within that inductive proof I am not sure about if I have understood it correctly. I put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\bigcup_{k=1}^N f^{-1}(k) \neq [N]$. So there exists $n \in [N]$ such that $n \notin f^{-1}(k)$ for any $k=1,\dots,N$. In other words, $f(k) \neq n$ for any $k=1,\dots,N$. By the pigeonhole principle, since there are $N$ values of $k$ and at most $N-1$ possible values of $f(k)$, there must exist $k_1 \neq k_2$ such that $f(k_1)=f(k_2)$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is injective.

Comment: I understand your approach but we have not introduced the pigeonhole principle, so I am wondering if I have missed something obvious or if it is possible to show the euqality in a more direct way?

Comment: Even without the formal statement of the pigeonhole principle, I would think it should be intuitively clear that $N$ distinct points can’t take on $N-1$ (or fewer) function values and have those all be distinct.